# Store object with double inheritance in vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector, multiple-inheritance

Let's say I got the following code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct AddColorToText
{
    void MakeItRed(std::string text);
    void MakeItGreen(std::string text);
    void MakeItBlue(std::string text);
};
```

So the first struct is a general struct that can add color to any text I throw in. It's just an example; the idea is that the first struct contain methods and then I got another struct with complementary methods:

```
struct AddEffects
{
    void MakeItFlash();
    void MakeItFadeGradually();
    void MakeItBounce();
};
```

And finally I got this third struct that inherit from the first and second struct and provides even more methods:

```
struct SuperText: public AddColorToText, public AddEffects
{
    void SetSize();
    void SetFont();
}
```

Now imagine that for some reason I must store a superText object in a vector of AddColorToText pointers:

```
SuperText TheSuperTextObject;
std::vector<AddColorToText*> TheVector;

TheVector.push_back(&TheSuperTextObject);
```

What is the best/cleanest way to get back the SuperText methods from the AddColorToText pointers vector?

```
TheVector[0]->SetSize??????
```

Comment: Your abstraction is faulty if you need it

Comment: `TheVector.push_back(&TheSuperTextObject);`, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your class declaration to enable polymorphism like so:

```
struct AddColorToText
{
    void MakeItRed(std::string text);
    void MakeItGreen(std::string text);
    void MakeItBlue(std::string text);
    virtual ~AddColorToText() {}
};
```

As correctly pointed out in the comments, you need at least one virtual method for polymorphism.

Then you could write

```
SuperText *sup = dynamic_cast<SuperText*>(TheVector[0]);
sup->SetSize();
```

Comment: ok I corrected the reference I forgot in the edit.  Thank you.

Comment: Isn't dynamic_cast for polymorphic only?

Comment: Yes and it is, since SuperText inherits from AddColorToText :) PS: It's not a reference! It's the address operator that retrieves the objects address in memory!

Comment: Yes, absolutely :)

Comment: @MatthiasGrün "polymorphic" means that it has at least one virtual function, which is not the case in OP's question.

Comment: Gotcha, so I would have to add SetSize() as virtual in AddColorToText struct and make SetSize() virtual in SuperText struct?

Comment: If you don't need it in AddColorToText just add an empty virtual destructor like I did in my answer.

Comment: You should check pointer, (else use `static_cast` directly...)